# Hiding ActionBar left blank space on top

Tags: android

I want to hide the ActionBar in one of my fragments but when i call

`((MainActivity) getActivity()).getActionBar().hide();`

on the fragment I get something like this

[image]

how to remove that blank space and make it "fullscreen" - i want the notification bar to be shown

[EDIT:]

Minimum SDK is not 4.0 but when i started this app i set it to 2.3, an i have to use appcompant

MainActivity xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
tools:context="com.mariusz.myapp.MainActivity" >

<!--
     As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions.
-->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />

<!--
     android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead.
-->
<!--
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container.
-->

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.mariusz.myapp.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

gallery fragment xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/gallery_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

**[EDIT SOLUTION]**

best solution for this was creating other activity to display images that have no actionbar

Comment: just a reminder to accept an answer that helped you out the most as a correct one.

Answer (score 2):

You should structure your activity so that it overlays the actionbar: here is an example of a theme you might use for it:

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

More info about [overlaying the Actionbar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html). also if you aren't planning to always hide the Actionbar, you might need to structure your layouts to account for it while it is visible. Please refer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757424/make-fragments-full-screen-programmatically) on how to do that. You might also consider refactoring your fragment to be a separate activity and just starting it in the full screen mode right away, by using the "NoTitlebarTheme" with that activity.

Comment: i have already done it before i post it `<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/NButton</item>
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/NEditText</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/NActionBar</item>
    </style>`

Comment: Whats your min SDK? Also, you have an extra "windowActionBarOverlay" item that is missing "android:" in front of it.

Comment: I think your activity and fragments XML would help, post them please

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, my problem was to include `fitsSystemWindows` tag in xml

Answer (score 0):

using this line only in that activity `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"` in manifest file

add the `getActionBar().hide();`  in activity class where your fragments called and use some other fragments in `getActionBar().show();`.

Comment: This will make an entire activity without the Actionbar which will affect other fragments, and it seems like he wants to be able to show/hide the Actionbar programmatically.

Comment: agree i need to do it in only one fragment

Comment: i checked that the things.i got the answers,try it ,let me inform.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity on create method put the following line of code

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: This can be used only before the content is added to the window - once the Activity is up and running, as it is when you add/remove a Fragment - it will throw an AndroidRuntimeException.