# what is the margin above the text

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-fullscreen

What can be this possibly be above the helloblank fragment text.I have used

> ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();

to hide the Action Bar. The code for the xml is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.anshul.testfindout.InfotabFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: refer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956902/hiding-actionbar-left-blank-space-on-top)

Comment: To get a clear picture of your layout, check View Hierarchy in android device monitor. Its locator is *Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor* in Android Studio

Comment: Can you post your tabs layout?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to hide the toolbar from all the pages use this in style.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

This will help you in hiding it from everywhere. !! If you need to do it in one single page. Then follow this rather then using getSupportActionBar

```
toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE); //INVISIBLE will leave space and GONE will help in removing the space also.
```

Hope this helps you...

To hide the toolbar from a particular Fragment first create an interface

```
public interface ControlToolbarInterface{
    void hideToolbar();
}
```

Then implement this interface in your activity

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ControlToolbarInterface{
    //remaining code
    @Override
    public void hideToolBar() {
         toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Then in your fragment

```
getActivity().hideToolBar();

//If still in doubt about the activity used you can further check instanceOf activity and will get the exact activity used
```

Comment: what if i want to hide the toolbar from fragment only?!! because I think this is toolbar is from the mainActivity. The aim is to remove from a particular fragment

Comment: Create a method in activity and call the same method from Fragment... I have update the ans with the same.

Comment: @ankit, awesome answer, but don't create a method in activity, use interface for such interactions. Memory considerations have to be made.

Comment: @MohammedAtif : that is also a good suggestion. Better to decouple the code to the max its always best for coding..

Comment: where it is required to create the interface because Iam seeing cyclic inheritance error

Comment: Don't make the object for an interface. Directly call the method from activity. You will not get the error.. 
Please accept the answer if this solves your problem

Comment: No. the problem is i have implemeted the interaface in the main activity and also defination is given in the main activity below onCreate. Is this an issue??

Comment: @anshulshankar create separate java class for interfaces.

Comment: No that is not an issue..!! If you have implemented the interface in the Mainactivity and your fragment is called from the same it will inherit the properties of that activity.!!  but you cannot declare the fragment inside the on create method that needs to be a stand alone class...

Comment: no @ankit the problem is you can not subclass the interface where you are implementing it. since in this case same interface might be called from multiple fragments, its advisable to create interface as separate class.

Comment: @MohammedAtif : I wrote above that you should create a stand alone class. That is also what you meant.!! We are saying the same thing.

Comment: @Anshulshankar : If this has solved your problem. Please accept the answer. Thanks